# How do you rename the _id field in mongoDB to a different key name?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to rename the _id field automatically generated by MongoDB to "ObjectID". ie, mutate the object so that `_id: xxxxx` becomes `ObjectID: xxxxx`. Here is the schema of my objects:

```
{
  skills: [ 'Programming', 'Design' ],
  paymentForms: [ 'Flat fee' ],
  _id: 6011a89084e07663d25e01af,
  title: 'Personal website development',
  description: 'I would like to have a personal website that showcases my resume and work portfolio.',
  otherSkills: '',
  price: '25-50',
  __v: 0
}
```

Currently, I am fetching the documents in my DB using a mongoose query, which returns an array of documents. I have tried two methods so far--after fetching this documents, I map through each element and rename the _id key, however, neither function works. Here is the code:

```
function renameKey(obj, oldKey, newKey) {
    if (oldKey !== newKey) {
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, oldKey))
        Object.defineProperty(obj, newKey,
            Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, oldKey));
        delete obj[oldKey];
    }
}
```

The problem with this method is that 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor' returns undefined. The second method I tried is:

```
const renameKey = (obj, oldKey, newKey) => {
    const targetKey = obj[oldKey];
    console.log(targetKey);
    obj[newKey] = targetKey;
    console.log(obj);

    delete obj[oldKey];
    return obj;
}
```

This is probably the typical way to rename keys. But it does not mutate my objects, and returns the same one. In both cases, the methods work for literal objects I create such as `{ _id: 10 }`, however, it doesn't work for the objects that are returned from my mongoose query.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with these methods, or give an alternate way to solve this problem, such as using mongoose projection to rename queries (idk if that's possible)?

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` field is internally required by MongoDB, so you won't be able to store documents without it.

The value of `_id` cannot be changed, so one possibility is to store that value again with a new field name.  Possibly using the pipeline form of an update.  This would introduce sync issues, but you could then query and simply project out the _id field.

If you change your queries to use the aggregation system, you could add a new field and remove the exist `_id` field in the pipeline:

```
{$addFields: {ObjectId: "$_id"}},
{$project: {_id: 0}}
```

Comment: how would I change queries to use the mongodb driver? I'm currently using mongoose but how do I switch?

Comment: Mongoose also supports aggregation